# Tracking movement of individuals

Tags: contact

I have a simple Salesforce set up of Accounts and Contacts. My contacts are associated to an account, but they may move to another account at some point in their career. I want to track that - what would be the best way of tracking this? I guess I could use field tracking on the Account field on the Contact object - but any other ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally people do this through affiliations. Affiliations is a custom object to track the relationship from a person to an org. The custom object would then have start/end dates for the relationship. There is a package on the Appexchange for this which is free.